# How much does an empty iron adjustable hand dumbbell weigh?

Tags: dumbbells

How much does the stick (bar) by itself weigh?
The bars (2) can be shown in the [picture](https://www.fitnessrocks.org/everything-know-adjustable-dumbbells/)

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, seems like a legit question to me even if the answer is that they aren’t standardized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spinlock dumbbells aren't standardised, so weight will vary from manufacturer to manufacturer. It will typically be around 2.5kg per handle, including the collars that lock the weights on, but to be certain you would really need to put them on a kitchen scale, luggage scale, etc and weigh them.